# Normal map bake creases on render

Tags: modeling, normals, baking

My pebble has small bumps where creases are if the shading is flat.

[image]

If it is on smooth shading, it has dips.

[image]

Edit

I figured out its only happening when they are on different shading modes (smooth and flat)

Now it only shows very visible creases when I back away from it.

Close:

[image]

Far:

[image]

I really hope someone can help me, thanks again!

Edit

System settings:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27603/discussion-on-question-by-aidan-pallian-normal-map-bake-creases-on-render).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save texture image then disable "Use Alpha" at image properties.

Comment: Alright one more question. How can I have 2 materials, one for normals and one for color?

Comment: If you want plain color, you can just change the Material's diffuse property. If you want a texture, you need to open an existing one or creating a new one and assign it at the Texture's properties panel.